# Dependency injection and loading objects data from XML file

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

How can Spring framework help me with creating objects with loaded data from XML file? I am new to Spring and I'd like to refactor my code to use dependency injection for my business objects. Is usage of DI is really needed here?

method responsible for fetching data:

```java
    private static List<Expenditure> fetchExpendituresFromXMLElement(List<Element> expenditureElements) {
        List<Expenditure> expenditures = new ArrayList<>();
        expenditureElements.forEach(expenditure -> {
            String[] dateString = expenditure.getChild("date").getValue().split("-");
            String moneyStr[] = expenditure.getChild("money").getValue().split(" ");
            try {
                expenditures.add(Expenditure.createExpenditure(expenditure.getChild("description").getValue(),
                        Money.of(Double.valueOf(moneyStr[1]), Monetary.getCurrency(moneyStr[0])),
                        LocalDate.of(Integer.valueOf(dateString[2]), Integer.valueOf(dateString[1]),
                                Integer.valueOf(dateString[0])),
                        ExpenditureType.valueOf(expenditure.getChild("type").getValue())));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        return expenditures;
    }
```

Expenditure class

```java
public class Expenditure implements Comparable<Expenditure> {
    private String description;
    private MonetaryAmount monetaryAmount;
    private LocalDate date;
    private ExpenditureType type;
...
}
```

Comment: XML is a Spring 1.0 style.  You should prefer annotations.  Look at Spring Boot version 2.1 or higher for the best way to proceed.   You should be able to write a Repository interface that has an implementation to read from serialized XML.  Is that really the best way to do it?  I would prefer JSON over XML.  You can use no SQL databases to persist those

Comment: DI might be useful here. In particular it is often useful where external resources are accessed by your program. By turning this into a `@Service` or `@Repository` bean you accomplish two things. 1) You can more easily write unit tests for code which calls this service. The unit test would mock the service, and use that to simulate different conditions without needing the external resource to actually be available. 2) Expenditures could later be moved (e.g. into a JSON file or a database) and the only thing that would change would be the implementation of the service.